# No puedo arreglar un IndexError: index 717 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 64

Tags: python, python-2.7

El tema es que estoy intentando hacer un software de reconocimiento de imágenes en una libreta de python que tiro en Google Cloud, y este es el código que escribí para verificar si funciona. Gracias por adelantado.

```
h,w = (64,64)
#I am doing an image recognition software, but i can't get the pictures to show
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(h*15,w*10))
offset = 900

train_dir = './base_de_dades/train/images/'#cambiar por test,var y train
train_image_names = os.listdir(train_dir)
train = np.array(Image.new('RGB',(h,w)))
for file in train_image_names:
    dir2 = os.path.join(train_dir,file)
    if dir2 != './base_de_dades/test/images/.ipynb_checkpoints':
        img = np.array(image.load_img(dir2,target_size=(h,w)))
        np.append(train,img, axis = 0)


test_dir = './base_de_dades/test/images/'#cambiar por test,var y train
test_image_names = os.listdir(test_dir)
test = np.array(Image.new('RGB',(h,w)))
for file in test_image_names:
    dir2 = os.path.join(test_dir,file)
    if dir2 != './base_de_dades/test/images/.ipynb_checkpoints':
        img = np.array(image.load_img(dir2,target_size=(h,w)))
        np.append(test,img, axis = 0)


for q in range(10):
    ranks_q = ranks[q*(offset+1),:]
    for i in range(15):
        print "nigger"
        new_image.paste(Image.fromarray(train[ranks_q[i]])), (h*(1+i),w*q)
```

## error aqui ^

```
    ima_q = Image.fromarray(test[q*(offset+1),...])
    ima_q = ImageOps.expand(ima_q, border=3, fill = 'green')

    new_image.paste(ima_q, (0,w*q))
plt.imshow(new_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola Nacho, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Creo que pensabas que estabas preguntando en el sitio inglés. ¿Puedes traducir la pregunta?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  esta en otro idioma

Comment: Voy a traducir, perdon